# Unstandardize z score values that have mu and standard deviation of 0 and 1 respectively

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

Is it possible for one to unstandardize z score values with mean 0 and standard deviation of 1 back to its original value, given that the mean and standard deviation of the original data is not available?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. Maybe the mean was originally $7$; maybe the mean was originally $789$. Maybe the standard deviation was originally $700$; maybe the standard deviation was originally $0.07$.

Those four combinations of means and standard deviations will give markedly different “original” data guesses.